# What is the formula for the radius of the photon sphere of a charge black hole?

Tags: black-holes, photons, reissner-nordstrom-metric

What is the formula for the radius of the photon sphere of a charge black hole?
I've found the formula for a Schwarzschild black hole and a Kerr black hole but despite some googling but I can't find an answer for a charged black hole

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> blademan9999 wrote: *"I can't find an answer for a charged black hole"*

Then you haven't looked [here](http://notizblock.yukterez.net/viewtopic.php?p=549#p549), for a Kerr Newman BH with spin $\rm a$ and charge $\rm Q$ you have

$$\rm 4 a^2 \ (r-Q^2)-(r^2-3 r+2 Q^2)^2=0$$

where the two solutions for $\rm r$ are for the pro- and retrograde photon orbits. For the orbits with polar angular momentum the equation is a little bit more complicated, but you can also find it in the link.

You get it by setting $\rm \ddot{r}=0, \ v_r=0, \ v_{\theta}^2+v_{\phi}^2=1$ and solve for $\rm r$, but the solution is not elegant in contrast to setting $\rm v_{\phi}=\pm 1, \ v_r=v_{\theta}=0$ (purely equatorial orbits), which gives the solution above.